# Fluent Validation not working on length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I am trying to get Fluent Validation to work correctly on my client side validation.  I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have a title that is required and it must be between 1 and 100 characters long.  So while I am typing in the title an error message displays that is not in my ruleset.  Here is my rule set:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Title)
   .NotEmpty()
   .WithMessage("Title is required")
   .Length(1, 100)
   .WithMessage("Title must be less than or equal to 100 characters");
```

Here is the error message that is displayed:

```
Please enter a value less than or equal to 100
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is my global.asax:

```
// FluentValidation
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
   new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory()));

ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new FluentValidationModelMetadataProvider(
   new AttributedValidatorFactory());
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works fine for me. Here are the steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM project using the default Visual Studio Template
2. Download the latest [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)
3. Reference the `FluentValidation.dll` and `FluentValidation.Mvc.dll` assemblies (be careful there are two folders inside the .zip: MVC2 and MVC3 so make sure to pick the proper assembly)

Add a model:

```
[Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator))]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and a corresponding validator:

```
public class MyViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Title)
           .NotEmpty()
           .WithMessage("Title is required")
           .Length(1, 5)
           .WithMessage("Title must be less than or equal to 5 characters");
    }
}
```

Add to `Application_Start`:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
    new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory()));

ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new FluentValidationModelMetadataProvider(
    new AttributedValidatorFactory());
```

Add a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding view:

```
@model SomeApp.Models.MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Title)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Now try to submit the form leaving the Title input empty => client side validation kicks in and the *Title is required message* is shown. Now start typing some text => the error message disappears. Once you type more than 5 characters in the input box the *Title must be less than or equal to 5 characters* validation message appears. So everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I have it exactly like you have it. With the help of Jeremy Skinner (of FluentValidation) I found the error.  In my textbox, I had the maxlength property as max.  This triggered the Jquery validation trigger incorrectly.

Comment: @Brendan, that's why when asking a question you should provide as much details about your scenario as you could. If those details are under source code form it is better. When I answer questions I always try to provide a full working source code so that people can easily reproduce the behavior on their machines. It also allows me to test and mock things quickly.