# Fluent Validation on AJAX Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, fluentvalidation

I am creating an action/view in ASP.net MVC that I would like to POST using AJAX / jQuery.
I am using Fluent Validation for the validation in my view models.

Is it possible to have client side validation when I do this? What would the script look like in order to trigger this client side validation using fluent validation?

Do I create a regular form and create a submit event using jquery and call something or would I just Ajax.BeginForm() instead?

Comment: refer to this post on SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713985/fluent-validation-not-working-on-length

Comment: @patel.milanb This post is not talking about an AJAX form using jQuery. I have client side validation working fine on a regular page that is not being submitted via AJAX. I am wondering if there is anything special I need to do to wire this up for a jQuery AJAX form submission...or if it is even possible to do so.

Comment: submitting form via ajax and validating the form using jquery? is that what you looking for?

Comment: I thought the question was clear. I want to know how I can get Fluent Validation working when submitting the form via AJAX and jQuery. I am using the Fluent Validation library. It works fine in a regular form post. How do I get it to work using an AJAX form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the jQuery unobtrusive validation with data annotations but it looks like you need the same settings as me (the first two options below) plus another step:

- Enable client validation in your view or web.config
- Enable unobtrusive validation in your view or in web.config
- Add the FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider to the ModelValidatorProviders collection

For the first two, see [Enabling Client-Side Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript). For the last one see [Fluent Validation: Integration with ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110142054/http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc).

If you want to submit the form via AJAX, you can trigger the validation on the whole form with `$('#form_selector').valid()` or on an individual input with `$('#input_selector').valid()`. The calls to valid() return true if the validation is successful (and false if not).

Comment: So what would your script look like in your view to submit the form via ajax? Is there something you would need to call to trigger the validation?

Comment: Ah! Yes, you can call either $('#form_selector').valid() to validate the whole form or $('#field_selector').valid() to validate a specific input. The `valid()` call will return true or false. Updated answer to include this -- I misunderstood too.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent Validation is a server-side validation library. Because of this, Fluent Validation supports some basic client-validations (like required, maxlength etc.) You can't use all server-side rules on client-side.

If you want to add fully client-side support to Fluent Validation, you need to add one more library to your project. [Form Helper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper) can be a solution for your problem.

https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper

You need to create your forms like this:

```
var formConfig = new FormConfig(ViewContext)
{
    FormId = "ProductForm",
    FormTitle = "New Product",
    BeforeSubmit = "ProductFormBeforeSubmit", // optional
    Callback = "ProductFormCallback" // optional,
};

// <form id="@formConfig.FormId" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save"
// ...

@await Html.RenderFormScript(formConfig)
```

After that you need to add [FormValidator] attribute to your action.

```
[HttpPost, FormValidator]
public IActionResult Save(FormViewModel viewModel)
```

Now all Fluent Validation rules work on client-side.